# Property ViewDidLoad Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am passing the NSManagedObjectContext from the AppDelegate to a ViewController.  I am then fetching, the results from Core Data.  However, the NSManagedObjectContext is always nil in the ViewDidLoad method, but not the ViewDidAppear method.

I understand the difference between the two methods, but I thought the I should be able to access properties from ViewDidLoad, I even notice that in Apple's sample code, they do this.

Should I just fetch in the ViewDidAppear?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This code crashings because my because my Context is nil
    NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Edit: I pass it like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];    
    rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    UINavigationController *rootNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Where are you passing the `NSManagedObjectContext` to your view controller?

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Can you please post that code? The state of your view controller in didFinishLaunching... depends on whether you're using a storyboard, or initing the view controller yourself, whether it is the initial view controller, etc.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2949216/839965

Comment: move it out of viewDidLoad. Messy solution is to set a timer to activate the method ~.5 seconds later (after the nib is loaded)

Comment: @DustinRowland thanks, I do not believe a timer is the solution

Comment: @BlackRider  The ViewController should get loaded when the application launches, since it is inside a tab bar.  All tabs are loaded at launch.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I found the solution/problem.  I'm not sure why exactly this would cause it, so if anyone has more insight, i'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem.  I used this init method in all my methods to set up the navigation title, and some other items.  I took this method out, and did all of this in the viewDidLoad, and the problem was solved.

If anyone has more insight on why this is causing the problem, i'd love to hear it.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) {

        // UINavigationBar
        self.navigationItem.title = @"List";

        // UINavigationBar Button
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add:)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I've put an edit that is explaining why it is bad to put view code in your init method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to give an answer that I would be certain of, but here is my thought.

Where you have wrote `// This code crashings because my because my Context is nil` the context is actually "not nil", but your NSFetchedResultController have not been initialized yet and is still `nil`

If you get access to your NSFetchedResultController in viewDidAppear it's because That is created after viewDidLoad in your code. You could move the creation of your NSFetchedResultController in the `getter` of that property or in ViewDidLoad.

I just wrote a test code in AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
listView *rootViewController = [[listView alloc] initWithNibName:@"listView" bundle:nil];    
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

In a UITableViewController subclass

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if (self.managedObjectContext)
{
    NSLog(@"Managed object ic not nil");
}
}
```

And the output is :  `testCoreDataLauchn[1690:207] Managed object ic not nil`

P-S : Sorry for the typos

---

This is to go with your solution / problem.

This is bad, because you are accessing view element in your init forcing the xib AKA views to be loaded right away. 
So your viewDidLoad will be call before you can assign something to your VC. 
Remove all view related code from your init method and place it in viewDidLoad and you should have a more normal view life cycle for your VC. 
Also keep in mind that in a navigation controller the views of a VC that is not on screen may get deallocated if a memory warning is issue. 
And in those time the init code won't get call again when the view need to be brought back to life, but viewDidload will be call again.

Comment: the context is nil, I did an NSLog of the object.  The code you wrote looks exactly the same.  The context is nil in viewDidLoad, but not viewDidAppear

Comment: @Vikings I would need to see more code, and the compiler is giving you no warning?

Comment: thanks, no warnings, all of my properties are nil in viewDidLoad, even if I try to set a string

Comment: @Vikings have you try to put a NSLog in viewDidLoad of your VC and just after the 'alloc' of the VC. You would then see if the assignment is made before or after view didLoad. If the assignment is done before you have an other problem.  The other problem could be with your property definition / synthesize AND / OR custom setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

How about exposing the `NSManagedObjectContext' as a property of the app delegate, and just reading that property in your view controller?

Comment: I know that will work, as well as just loading it in viewDidAppear.  I was just looking for a solution, because it should be available in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @Vikings: your problem seems related to the one I had: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858939/segue-destination-view-controller-weirdness. I ended up implementing a workaround.